# Logarithm of Gaussian function is whether convex or nonconvex?

Tags: probability-distributions, convex-analysis

I have a gaussian distribution such as
$$P(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac {(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$
As my knowledge, $P(x)$ is non convex function interm of $x$. However, if I map it to $log$ space, Does it become convex function? If it is convex, please prove help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$ and $\log(a^b)=b\log a$......

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, note that
$$
\log P(x)=\log\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\right]-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}.
$$

This is a downward-facing parabola; its second derivative is 
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\log P(x)\right]=-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}<0.
$$

Comment: So, It will becomes convex function in log space, Right?

Comment: Yes.  It has a negative second derivative.

Comment: By standard nomenclature, its log is concave, not convex.

Comment: @p.s. Very true.

Answer (score 3):

The Gaussian density function is quasiconcave but not concave. Moreover, it is log-concave because log P(x) is essentially a negative quadratic function.